# JavaScript: Suma de 2 elementos de un array que coincida con un entero predefinido

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, bucles, sum

Tengo que resolver este código de tal forma que, si la *suma de 2 elementos* cualquiera, *dentro del array*, coincide con el var `n` (predefinido), sea **true**. De lo contrario sea **false**.

Les comparto mi código:

```
function sumArray(array, n) {

  // La función llamada 'sumArray' recibe como argumento un arreglo de números ordenados llamado 'array' y un número
  // entero llamdo 'n' y debe devolver true si alguna combinación de dos números cualesquiera del arreglo sumados
  // dan n, y devuelva false si ninguna combinación de dos números sumados da como resultado el número n.
  // Ej:
  // sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)  debería devolver true ya que 2 + 11 = 13
  // sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14)  debería devolver false ya que no es posible sumar 14 con dos números del arreglo
  // Pista: Podes usar bucles/ciclos anidados
  // Aclaración: No es válido sumar el mismo número dos veces
  // Ej:
  // sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 4)  Si bien 2 + 2 = 4 no está permitido sumar el mismo número dos veces
  // por lo tanto también debería devolver false en este caso
  // Tu código aca:

  var num1 = array[0];

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > num1) {
      num1 = array[i]
    }
  }

  var num2 = array[0];

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > num2) {
      num2 = array[i]
    }
  }

  if (num1 + num2 === n) {
    return true
  }

  return false

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edito la respuesta, este otro método diria que está más optimizado:

```js
function sumArray(array, n) {

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[i] + array[j] === n && array[i] !== array[j]) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
  return false
}
array = [2, 5, 7, 10, 11, 15, 20]
n = 7
result = sumArray(array, n);
console.log(result);
```

En esta nueva edición he sustituido el `map` de la respuesta anterior por un doble bucle `for`, para así forzar la salida enseguida del bucle cuando se encuentre un caso `true`, cosa que con `map` no está permitido hacer.

La explicación viene a ser la misma, es decir, primero hacemos un buble del array usando la variable `i` y luego un segundo bucle dentro del primero identico pero con la variable `j` para distinguirlos, y el resto es similar a mi anterior respuesta, solo que cuando por fin encontremos un caso `true` ya salimos de ambos bucles con `return true`, que nos sacará de la función (dentro del segundo bucle) y si por el contrario, se ejecutan completamente ambos bucles será porque no ha encontrado nada y salimos con `return false`.

De este modo acortamos las iteraciones y no hace falta recorrerlo todo para ver el resultado, si éste ya ha sido `true` en cualquiera de las iteraciones de los ciclos.

### Respuesta original (no optimizada)

Yo lo haria así:

```js
function sumArray(array, n) {

  let result = false;

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array.map(function(x) {
      if (array[i] + x === n && array[i] !== x) {
        result = true
      }
    })
  }
  return result
}
array = [2, 5, 7, 10, 11, 15, 20]
n = 7
result = sumArray(array, n);
console.log(result);
```

**Explicación**

Primero definimos la varialbe `result` como `false` para inicializar la variable.

Luego dentro del bucle que ya tenias puesto ejecutamos un `map` del mismo `array`, pasándole la función de suma de todos los elementos que estan siendo itinerados por cada uno de los elementos del `map`, que es la misma `array`, y teniendo en cuenta que no debe ser el mismo número del `map` y el itinerado con el `for`, así:

```javascript
if (array[i] + x === n && array[i] !== x) {
```

En caso afirmativo cambiamos el valor de la variable `result` por **true**.

Cuando termina devolvemos el valor de `result`, el cual sera `true` si ha encontrado algo, o bien `false` si nunca se ha cumplido la condición.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora ya se para que sirve el .map

Comment: Si funcionó! :)

Comment: Ahora voy a cambiar un poco la respuesta, dejando abajo lo del map, pues no está bien optimizada, y te contaré el porque.

Comment: Wow, y yo pensaba que lo erróneo estaba en utilizar un doble bucle for

Comment: Estoy comenzando en Javascript y la programación, y me encanta la lógica que hay que usar :o
Muchas gracias, nuevamente!

Comment: Entendido, ya los borro!